# Add new attribute to JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

What i can to do is extend my JSON object with a new attrubute.

E.g

```
  var jsonText = {
            "Repeats": 1,
            "Trials": 4,
            "GroupName": "Mobile phones",
            "targets": [
                    {
                        "name": "Apple",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Samsung",
                    }
                ]}
```

What I would like to end up with is the inclusion of a new item so extend the object so it then looks something like.

```
  var jsonText = {
            "NewItem" : NewValue,
            "Repeats": 1,
            "Trials": 4,
            "GroupName": "Mobile phones",
            "targets": [
                    {
                        "name": "Apple",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Samsung",
                    }
                ]}
```

Comment: `jsonText.NewItem = NewValue`?

Comment: As you maybe know, the order of the properties does not matter at all.

Comment: I know the order doesn't matter, I added it at the start to make it more obvious to see the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a JavaScript object literal, not a JSON string. You can interact with it like a normal object literal:

```
jsonText.NewItem = "NewValue";
```

If you did actually have a JSON string you could first parse it into a JavaScript object and then handle it in the same way, and then serialize it back into a JSON string. For example:

```
var jsonText = '{ "Repeats": 1, "Trials": 4 }',
    actualObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
actualObj.newItem = "New Value";
jsonText = JSON.stringify(actualObj);
```